# use 'as' in query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this and type is innodb and id and sid are indexed.

```
  id | sid
  ##########
   1 | 100
   1 | 101
   1 | 102
   1 | 103
   1 | 104
   1 | 105
   2 | 100
   2 | 101
   3 | 100
   3 | 101
```

I need id's have sid 100,...105 like id=1.
I have this query

```
select t1.id
  from test as t1, test as t2, test as t3,
       test as t4, test as t5, test as t6
 where t1.sid=100
   and t2.sid=101
   and t3.sid=102
   and t4.sid=103
   and t5.sid=104
   and t6.sid=105
   and t1.id = t2.id = t3.id = t4.id = t5.id = t6.id
```

but phpmyadmin hangs when I run query.
The number of records is 2000.

What is optimized query?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What exactly do you want to do with that query?

Comment: Apparently, he wants to pick out all the ID values where the ID has associated with it each of the sid values in { 100 .. 105 }.  If one of the sid values is missing, omit the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surprising that the SQL statement shown compiles/runs.

However, you can probably rescue it by rewriting what is currently the last line to:

```
select t1.id
  from test as t1, test as t2, test as t3,
       test as t4, test as t5, test as t6
 where t1.sid = 100
   and t2.sid = 101
   and t3.sid = 102
   and t4.sid = 103
   and t5.sid = 104
   and t6.sid = 105
   and t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.id = t3.id
   and t1.id = t4.id
   and t1.id = t5.id
   and t1.id = t6.id;
```

---

> Is this query optimal?

Given your comment to Maulik Vora's answer that the range { 100 .. 105 } is just an example, then we need to know whether it is always 6 values or whether it could be 5 or 7 or some other number.  However, it is likely that the optimal structure uses a temporary table (call it ListToMatch with a non-null unique column SID) containing whatever values are needed, and that the query is:

```
SELECT T.ID
  FROM Test AS T JOIN ListToMatch AS L ON T.SID = L.SID
 GROUP BY T.ID
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ListToMatch);
```

You insert the set of values you're interested in to ListToMatch; you can then get the list of ID values that match.  This is likely to be more nearly optimal, not least because it adapts to 1 value and 100 values as easily as it does to 6, whereas rewriting the SQL with a 100-way self-join doesn't bear much thinking about.

Comment: Probably not - but working is better than non-working.  I'm not entirely sure why the original hung, but it is likely to do with how that last line is interpreted.

Comment: is join better one if it is possible in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id from (select id, max(sid) as mxsid, min(sid) as mnsid from test
group by id having count(id) = 6) as t2 
where t2.mxsid = 105 and t2.mnsid = 100
```

Comment: I originally said '+1 for the alternative approach, but why not: `SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 6 AND MIN(id) = 100 AND MAX(id) = 105`?'  Then I realized: suppose there was an entry in the table for id = 1 with sid = 99 (or 106).  This should still allow id = 1 to be selected by the query.  So, the revised query needs to be: SELECT id FROM test WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 105 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 6 AND MIN(id) = 100 AND MAX(id) = 105`.  The 6 corresponds to '105 - 100 + 1', of course.

Comment: With the condition in the WHERE clause, the condition on MAX and MIN is not needed.  But see my answer for the generalization of the queries that deals with non-contiguous lists of interesting SID values.